# VS Code Extension and command line tool

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I would like to create a command line tool (CLI), that can be run from the terminal, that will do some stuff in the background, then open a WebView of the results in VS Code.  I'm unsure of whether or not this would require 2 components or can be completely run inside of a VS Code Extension.  If running separately, I would assume there would need to be some communication layer between the command line process and the extension itself.  What is the best approach?

An example of the command:
hydra generate app

The WebView would show the results of the process and a TreeView (HTML) of the results.  The HTML would need to be interactive but I have the HTML working as standalone for now.